# Shadow a global variable with a modified copy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, shadowing

Please note: this is *not* a question about how to change a global variable inside a function body. I understand the `global` keyword.

My script has a bunch of global configuration variables. I want write a function that shadows one of those global variables in the local namespace (called `modified_procedure()` below) and calls another function that refers to the configuration variable. I.e.,

```
PARAMETER = 1

def procedure():
    return PARAMETER * 3

def modified_procedure():
    PARAMETER += 1
    return procedure()
```

This fails because `PARAMETER` occurs in the body of `modified_procedure()` so the interpreter considers it a local variable and doesn't look it up in the global namespace. I'm not trying to change the global variable `PARAMETER`; I am trying to shadow it in `modified_procedure()`'s namespace.

I can think of a couple of inconvenient solutions:

- OOPify the script so that configuration variables are object attributes and I can create a subclass with a new `procedure()`
- Use `global` in `modified_procedure()` to modify `PARAMETER` and then restore it before returing the result of `procedure()`

Can I do it by shadowing `PARAMETER`? If so, how?

Comment: You could try `nonlocal` instead of `global`. I'd test it myself but I'm stuck with a very old version of Python.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense You'll get an error before you can even call the function. `nonlocal` is, sadly, only for non-global names (i.e. closures).

Comment: I don't think there is a `nonlocal` keyword in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for amounts to dynamic scoping. Python, like most languages still used today (notable exceptions being Perl and Emacs Lisp) does not support dynamic scoping at all, opting for lexical scoping.

You could alter the `procedure` function object to replace its `__globals__`. But this would be even more hacky, and more code to boot. If you can change `procedure` to accept a parameter, do that. If it must refer to a global, temporarily altering the global is going to be the least painful and astonishing approach.

Comment: Running into this finally clarified what is meant by dynamical and lexical scope, glad you pointed out my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly hackish, but you can use the approach below to make things work.

First, define the inital method as below:

```
PARAMETER = 1

def procedure(PARAMETER = PARAMETER):
    return PARAMETER * 3
```

Now, in the second method, you can use the [`globals()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and call it with the modified `PARAMETER`:

```
def modified_procedure_v1():
    PARAMETER = globals()["PARAMETER"] + 1
    return procedure()
```

You can even call the first method from within a modified method using the updated PARAMETER value in following manner:

```
def modified_procedure_v2():
    PARAMETER = globals()["PARAMETER"] + 1
    return procedure(PARAMETER)
```

And so, the end result becomes:

```
>>> modified_procedure_v1() #uses global PARAMETER
3
>>> modified_procedure_v2() #uses PARAMETER value local to this method
6
```

Comment: Is the middle/second snippet supposed to have the same effect as the last/third?

Comment: @delnan No. In the middle one, you don't use the updated value of PARAMETER, in the last one, you use the update value of PARAMETER

Comment: Good, because the surrounding text makes it sound like it does and that would be wrong.

Comment: @delnan I have edited the answer, I realized it was actually pretty ambiguous earlier. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: I don't think the first snippet is necessary for the second to work, since accessing `globals()` instead of `PARAMETER` on the right side of the assignment avoids the arrow. I chose @delnan's because it gave me a deeper understanding but yours is the hack I need.

Comment: @katriel True that, the first snippet is necessary only to demonstrate the third snippet. Just like you have a need for snippet 2 currently, you may also need something along the lines of snippet 3 in future.

Answer (score 1):

You could (ab)use the `mock` library to temporarily change the value of `PARAMETER` as recorded in `procedure`'s global scope:

```
import mock

def modified_procedure():
    with mock.patch.dict(procedure.func_globals, PARAMETER=PARAMETER+1):
        return procedure()
```

In Python 3, where `mock` is part of the `unittest` package instead of a third-party library, it would be

```
from unittest import mock

def modified_procedure():
    with mock.patch.dict(procedure.__globals__, PARAMETER=PARAMETER+1):
        return procedure()
```

Without using `mock`, you could try something like

```
def modified_procedure():
    # Support Python 2 and 3. 
    try:
       d = procedure.__globals__
    except AttributeError:
       d = procedure.func_globals
    # Ensure that procedure()'s globals are restored
    # even if it raises an exception.
    try:
       d['PARAMETER'] += 1
       return procedure()
    finally:
       d['PARAMETER' -= 1
```